# C# .net PrintTicket XML is not well-formed (using badge printer)

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printdialog

Using .NET 3.5 and 4.5 I'm able to print a simple canvas with a red rectangle in the centre with no problems using PrintDialog.PrintVisual(). These print jobs are sent to CutePDF and a standard printer and they both work fine.

However, I'm now trying to send the same print job to a Javelin card printer, it works when the test project is set to .NET 3.5 but if I go any higher (4/4.5) it throws an exception. The exception is as below:

> Additional information: PrintTicket XML is not well-formed. Parameter
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemakeywords:PageMediaSizeMediaSizeHeight
>   is referenced, but not defined
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemakeywords:PageMediaSizeMediaSizeHeight%20is%20referenced%2c%20but%20not%20defined
>   . AAA

I need this to work in .NET 4.5 so let's focus on that. So, next I created two PrintDialog objects, PrintDialog1 is created by myself telling it which printer to use, PrintDialog2 uses the Show() method so I can select the printer from the dialog. **PrintDialog1 throws the same exception. PrintDialog2 works fine.**

(I created the PrintQueue and PrintTicket in the way shown on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket(v=vs.110).aspx)

If I set the PrintTicket of PrintDialog1 to PrintDialog2 then it works, like so:

PrintDialog1.PrintTicket = PrintDialog2.PrintTicket;

However I cannot show a dialog during the print, so I cannot access the **working** PrintTicket. I have compared them side by side, the only apparent differences are Collation and PageMediaSize, both of which I set to the same values as PrintDialog2.PrintTicket and still it throws the exception.

Any ideas on what's happening? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: having worked with card printers in the past I know how much of a pain this can be.  what is the exact make model and age of the printer?

Comment: Also, have you tried doing .Net Framework upgrade on the test project that works?

Comment: One further comment, (yes me again) can you show us all of your code tha you are using to interact with the image and the printer

Comment: @CodeWarrior hey, thanks for all the attention! It's just been resolved thankfully, in the preferences of the printer there is a Paper Source field with the options Auto, Automatically Select and Manual. Apparently it needs to be on Automatically Select instead of Auto when using .NET4 and above. Who knew?! I have no idea what the differences between the two are, and I have no idea why it caused such a negative affect in a newer .NET. Oh well.. thanks anyway, I appreciate the interest!